# How to determine if you can write to a directory with SFTP because of your group?

Tags: ssh, permissions, sftp

Quoting [How to determine if you can write to a file with SFTP because of your group?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37038811/569976) ,

> You could do `mode & 00002` to see if a [directory] is writable by the public
>   and you could get a directory listing to and see if the owner of `.`
>   matches the user that you logged in with (although `stat` doesn't
>   usually return the `longname` for SFTPv3 servers, which is what you'd
>   need to get the username from that) but what about group permissions?

In the answer to that post it was suggested that a better way to test the writeability of a file with SFTP was to actually open that file for writing. eg. something analogous to `fopen('filename.ext', 'w');`.

My question is...  what's the best way to determine the writeability of a *directory* with SFTP? You can't open a directory for writing like you can a file. My best guess: just attempt to upload a temporary file in the directory in question?

Like maybe use SSH_FXF_CREAT and SSH_FXF_EXCL? Altho the possibility that the file might already exist kinda complicates things. I guess a directory listing could be obtained and then one could attempt to upload a filename that *doesn't* exist but, the fact that this would require read permissions not withstanding it'd also not work as well if the directory was super large.

Any ideas?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl - any ideas?

Comment: To the person who voted to close this...  do you even know what SSH_FXF_CREAT and SSH_FXF_EXCL even are? They're part of the SFTP spec: https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-secsh-filexfer-02. I'm not asking how to use an arbitrary SFTP client - I'm asking what combination of of SFTP packets, as described in the IETF drafts, would need to be utilized to make a specific determination. Saying "you can do sftp --opt whatever" to get the desired answer is NOT what I'm looking for. Maybe I should post this question on travel.stackexchange.com because I'm asking about how the packets should travel!

Answer (score 1):

What about a login script which would do a [`touch`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/touch.1.html) on that directory with that user?

If `sshd` would be used you could use a [`pam_script`](https://linux.die.net/man/5/pam_script) (pam auth module to execute a script) simply  to simply do a `touch testing_file_creation` in your directory.  You would need to add into your pam sshd configuration.

If the directory would **not** be writable you would get a message during your login
`touch: testing_file_creation: Permission denied`.  Of course, you could do more fancy stuff with that but this would be the very basic.

Comment: SFTP doesn't implement touch, as such. It can be emulated with SSH_FXP_OPEN with SSH_FXF_WRITE, SSH_FXF_CREATE, SSH_FXF_EXCL as flags but that wouldn't work with directories. Updating the login script could work but sometimes servers will have SFTP access without shell access (or rather, they'll have a jail shell or some such), which would prevent that approach from working in a pure SFTP client.

Comment: @neubert this was a general idea.  If you can emulate the behaviour there is no difference.  If you try to perform `SSH_FXP_OPEN` with `SSH_FXF_WRITE` `SSH_FXF_CREAT` ( with `SSH_FXF_EXCL`) in the directory with `O_TRUNC` specified (zero lenght).  If you won't have writting permission then you will get message `SSH_FX_PERMISSION_DENIED`.  If this action would be performed by daemon itself you won't need a shell permission.

Comment: My testing suggests it doesn't work like that. When I send the SSH_FXP_OPEN request I get an SSH_FXP_STATUS response back that says "Failure". What I should be getting back if I had write permission was SSH_FXP_HANDLE but I'm not. https://pastebin.com/CHST3z0a shows what I am getting. I tried with with just SSH_FXF_WRITE as well and got https://pastebin.com/Q9rsQcpQ. The thing is... the /root/.ssh directory that I'm testing on *is* writable (I'm logged in as root). I know this because I was able to upload a test file without issue.

Comment: And tbh idk that that behavior surprises me. https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-secsh-filexfer-02 (SFTPv3) has SSH_FXP_OPEN for opening files and SSH_FXP_OPENDIR for opening directories.  The former has a field for flags wherein you can request a file be opened for writing - the latter does not. You don't write to a directory by doing SSH_FXP_OPENDIR - you write to a directory by doing SSH_FXP_OPEN not on the directory but on a (new) file *within* the directory with SSH_FXF_CREAT. Doing it on an old file is insufficient because an old file could have it's own permissions independent of dir

Comment: @neubert then probably the only option is to upload a test file.